# Div centering vertically when mobile page is at top, but when we scroll down the page, error is occuring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a cordova app. When I click on div, its conponents are shown and the popup has to be in the center of screen. This is my code.

```
        var new_height = $('#' + id).height() + 20;
        var new_width = $('#' + id).width() * 0.97;

        $('#' + id + '_popup').width(new_width);

        var move_up = $('#' + id + '_popup').height() / 2;

        $('#' + id + '_popup').css({
            "overflow-y": 'auto',
            'transform': 'translateY(-' + $('#' + id + '_popup').height() / 2 + 'px)'
        });

        $('#' + id + '_popup').css("z-index", '3000');
```

But when I scroll the page, the new div is not displaying in the center of div but above. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve perfect center only with CSS, so remove that useless calculations and use `transform` like this:

```css
.red {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.green {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /*safari iOS*/
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="green">
  </div>
</div>
```

With this code doesn't matter the sizes of the boxes, it will be always at the center of the screen.

You can change `position` to `fixed` or `relative` and still will work.